# Is it possible to install Mac OS on a Pi 4B 8GB?

Tags: pi-4, macos

I am wondering if I can install Some version of Mac OS on my Pi 4B with 8GB ram and 128GB SSD card. I heard a rumour that it is possible but thought I would ask this community for advice.
I did manage to install Ubuntu 22.04 on it.

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I did some research and apparently Mac OS only runs on Apple hardware. It is proprietary software. There are themes, however that I can install that mimic the Mac OS desktop interface.

Comment: Not only that, but MacOS runs on only 3 (4?) processors (2 for the current version), and none of those are the cpu on the pi, and it expects specific hardware devices for which it has drivers, and none of the devices on the pi are on that list.  This is true for any OS, you can't just plop a random OS on random hardware.

Answer (score 1):

there is iraspbian, which mimics OSX's look.

There is also MacintoshPi, which runs a classic macos7/8 via emulation.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you can, it is against the license of MacOS and Apple actively do what they can to make this hard to do.